# Is there a risk to updating Windows with a poor internet connection?

Tags: networking, router, windows-update

In short, does Windows Update do an integrity (hash) check on all of the files that it downloads?

For example, I have a crappy router that drops packets, I am receiving a better router in the mail in a few days, but I don't want to wait that long to set up my new computer. Is there a risk to setting up my computer with the poor connection?

Comment: Windows handles this automatically.  Actually.  Basic networking drivers handle this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a matter of using programs like CCleaner, nor worrying about jitter. Windows itself is certainly able to handle the situation - as long as you get *some* packets fine, you'll *eventually* get everything.

As Ramhound said in the comment, basic networking drivers handle packet loss or corruption automatically. But even if the connection is THAT bad, Windows' job is to make sure it gets the file flawlessly.

If you manage to *eventually* download a full update, the TCP stack will make sure every packet looks okay, and even if any one gets corrupted in such a way that TCP can't find out (that is a mathematically possible situation), digital signatures in the updates will make sure Windows will detect a corrupted update. Comparing hashes is only a part of the process.

If you're able to get into a situation where a network corruption would bypass both the TCP checksums and the Windows' digital signatures, congratulations. You are more likely to win every lottery that has happened, and that will happen for the next millenia.

That being said, update your computer. You'll be fine.